# Angular 8 routing not navigating properly

Tags: angular-routing, angular8

I've created a separate routing module for the client side works called client.module.ts in my application and calling it in app.module. But due to some issues after navigating to the routes, the content of the component is not showing. console is showing nothing...just the footer is coming since I placed it in app.component.html  Below is my app.module setup

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ClientModule } from './client/client-routing/client.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './client/home/home.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './client/footer/footer.component';
import { FeaturedBlogComponent } from './client/featured-blog/featured-blog.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    FeaturedBlogComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My client-routing.module.ts file is as below

```js
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BlogListComponent } from '../blog-list/blog-list.component';
import { BlogDetailComponent } from '../blog-detail/blog-detail.component';
import { AboutComponent } from '../about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from '../contact/contact.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'blogs', component: BlogListComponent},
  {path: 'blog/:_id', component: BlogDetailComponent},
  {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
  {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ClientRoutingModule { }
```

Below is the client.module.ts file which I'm importing to the app.module

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ClientRoutingModule } from './client-routing.module';
import { BlogListComponent } from '../blog-list/blog-list.component';
import { BlogDetailComponent } from '../blog-detail/blog-detail.component';
import { AboutComponent } from '../about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from '../contact/contact.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [BlogListComponent, BlogDetailComponent, AboutComponent, ContactComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ClientRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class ClientModule { }
```

You can also check my app.component.html which is as below

```html
<app-home *ngIf="router.url == '/'"></app-home>
<app-featured-blog *ngIf="router.url == '/'"></app-featured-blog>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Whenever I'm trying to access the routes that I created, only the footer is getting loaded and nothing else. The home page is working absolutely fine.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no..nothing is coming up in the console

Comment: Do you have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app.component.html?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't comment yet on questions.. I would wonder how the root module would know to use the child routes.  Don't you need to tell the Root routing paths when to load the Child routing paths?  All of my child routes are loaded using a line like this:

```
{ path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./client/client-routing/client.module').then(m => m.ClientModule) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable routing tracing by adding "enableTracing: true" in NgModule

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })]
```

it helps to troubleshoot router related issue